# file sending using php

Tags: php, jquery

can we use php to send a file to another like in MSN Messenger? I am working on a chat script and was wondering if its possible or not to send a file to the other person during chat?

i am using jquery/mysql/textfiles/php for this script

Comment: "Send" how? Using what method? Do you mean as a file download in a browser?

Comment: no... like file transfer... there should be any way like socket/tunnel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is the communication between your clients done?

You cannot send a file from a client directly to another client using PHP, as it's a server side language.

You could however upload the file to your server, and then send a link to the recieving client for download.

Comment: there should be any way like socket/tunnel

Comment: As @Alexn mentioned, PHP is server-side. There's nothing on the client that would know how to handle an incoming/outgoing file (unless you used a Java/Flash/Silverlight plugin as the chat client and used PHP on the back-end to coordinate the connection.